# How to seek in a file in CLISP?

Tags: clisp

I see in the CLISP implementation notes the availability of #'read-char-sequence and #'read-byte-sequence.  Hot stuff.

But is it possible to seek to a particular point in a file before doing the desired reading?

I've searched both Steele's Common Lisp the Language and the CLISP implementation notes, and not found an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `file-position`.

```
(file-position my_stream)
```

This returns the current position in the file.

```
(file-position my_stream n)
```

This sets it to the nth position.

However there are sometimes problems with using this in Unix. Make sure you do not go beyond EOF.

Comment: (rolls eyes) My searching skills are deficient.  All I sought was "seek", not "position".  Thanks for the answer.  As to "Make sure ...", readers should be advised that `(file-length my-stream)` can make this easier.